# In the card game bridge, the 52 cards are dealt out equally to 4 players

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I misunderstand conditional probability as in this problem

In the card game bridge, the 52 cards are dealt out equally to 4 players—called East,
West, North, and South. If North and South have a total of 8 spades among them,
what is the probability that East has 3 of the remaining 5 spades?

My calculation is.

Let  E denote:" East has 3 of the remaining 5 spades" and F:" North and South have a total of 8 spades among them".

Since $  P(E|F)= \frac {P(EF)}  {P(F)} $

For $P(F)= \frac {{13 \choose 8}  * {39 \choose 18}} {{52 \choose 26}}$ =0,161

And $P(EF)= \frac {{13 \choose 8}*{39 \choose 18}*{5 \choose 3}*{18 \choose 10}}{{52\choose 26}*{26 \choose 13}}$ =0,32.
But the answer is 0,339. What is wrong with my calculation?

Comment: Should $18\choose 10$ be $21\choose10$?

Comment: This is the remaining of cards which are not spade.

Comment: North and South have 18 non-spades, so East-West have 21 non-spades for East to choose from.

Comment: Yes you are right but it still doesnt give correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation of $P(EF)$ is not correct and should be:$$P(EF)=\frac{\binom{13}{3,2,8}\binom{39}{10,11,18}}{\binom{52}{13,13,26}}=\frac{\frac{13!}{3!2!8!}\frac{39!}{10!11!18!}}{\frac{52!}{13!13!26!}}$$

There are e.g. $\frac{13!}{3!2!8!}$ ways to divide $13$ spades in such a way that East gets $3$ and West gets $2$ of them.

Answer (score 4):

We need to condition on the $26$ cards received by East and West.  If North and South have eight spades between them, they also have $26 - 8 = 18$ non-spades.  That means of the $26$ cards East and West receive, $13 - 8 = 5$ are spades and $39 - 18 = 21$ are non-spades.

We wish to find the probability that East receives three of the five remaining spades.  East must receive $13$ of the remaining $26$ cards.  If East receives $3$ of the remaining five spades, then East must also receive $13 - 3 = 10$ of  the $21$ remaining non-spades.  Hence, the probability that East receives three of the five remaining spades
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{21}{10}}{\dbinom{26}{13}}$$

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to solve it is to just focus on dealing out the necessary number of spades from those remaining in the **hands** of East and West, and forget about the rest. !

$$Pr = \large\frac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{26}{5}} =\frac{39}{115}, \approx 0.33913$$

Comment: @RossMillikan  The rationale for true blue anil's answer is that there are $26$ positions to fill, $13$ for East and $13$ for West.  Of these, we must choose $5$ for spades, of which $3$ of the $13$ positions for East must be filled with spades and $2$ of the $13$ positions for West must be filled with spades.